# How import a HTML code to JSF page?

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I'm trying to import this [page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5714646/Highcharts-2.2.0/examples/pie-donut/index.htm) to my JSF page which is gonna have database to get the data, to be more interactive.

So I did this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <h:outputScript>
            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
                    categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
                    name = 'Browser brands',
                    data = [{
                            y: 55.11,
                            color: colors[0],
                            drilldown: {
                                name: 'MSIE versions',
                                categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                                data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                                color: colors[0]
                            }
                        }, {
                            y: 21.63,
                            color: colors[1],
                            drilldown: {
                                name: 'Firefox versions',
                                categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
                                data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
                                color: colors[1]
                            }
                        }, {
                            y: 11.94,
                            color: colors[2],
                            drilldown: {
                                name: 'Chrome versions',
                                categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                                    'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
                                data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
                                color: colors[2]
                            }
                        }, {
                            y: 7.15,
                            color: colors[3],
                            drilldown: {
                                name: 'Safari versions',
                                categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                                    'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
                                data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
                                color: colors[3]
                            }
                        }, {
                            y: 2.14,
                            color: colors[4],
                            drilldown: {
                                name: 'Opera versions',
                                categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
                                data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
                                color: colors[4]
                            }
                        }];


                // Build the data arrays
                var browserData = [];
                var versionsData = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    // add browser data
                    browserData.push({
                        name: categories[i],
                        y: data[i].y,
                        color: data[i].color
                    });

                    // add version data
                    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].drilldown.data.length; j++) {
                        var brightness = 0.2 - (j / data[i].drilldown.data.length) / 5 ;
                        versionsData.push({
                            name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
                            y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
                            color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
                        });
                    }
                }

                // Create the chart
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Total percent market share'
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            shadow: false
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Browsers',
                        data: browserData,
                        size: '60%',
                        dataLabels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                            },
                            color: 'white',
                            distance: -30
                        }
                    }, {
                        name: 'Versions',
                        data: versionsData,
                        innerSize: '60%',
                        dataLabels: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                // display only if larger than 1
                                return this.y > 1 ? '<b>'+ this.point.name +':</b> '+ this.y +'%'  : null;
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                });
            });

    </h:outputScript>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/javascript/highchart/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/javascript/highchart/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

But when I try to run gives me this error:

```
Error Parsing /showroom/report.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 71] The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

The referred line is :

```
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

I don't know what's wrong with this, I always import the HTML code to JSF and never happens this error.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not HTML code, this is JavaScript code. The JavaScript language has several operators which are [special characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) in XML (Facelets is a XHTML+XML based view technology), such as `<`, `>` and `&`. They needs to be escaped to `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;` to prevent the XML parser from literally interpreting them as XML.

```
for (var i = 0; i &lt; data.length; i++) {
```

An alternative is to wrap the entire JS code inside a `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` block.

Better, however, is to put that JS code in its own JS file and include it by `<h:outputScript>`, e.g.

```
<h:outputScript name="global.js" />
```

#### See also:

- [Mozilla developer documentation - Writing JavaScript for XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you're not taking benefit of JSF resource management. I'd suggest to replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/javascript/highchart/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/javascript/highchart/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

by

```
<h:outputScript name="javascript/highchart/highcharts.js" />
<h:outputScript name="javascript/highchart/modules/exporting.js" />
```

This way you don't need to fiddle with error prone URI-relative paths.

---

**Update**: as per comments, you'd like to pass some Java variables to the script file. You could do that by printing a Java object (which can be a javabean or a `Map<String, Object>`) as JSON object as if it is a global JS variable.

```
<h:outputScript>var data = ${bean.dataAsJson};</h:outputScript>
```

with e.g. (with help of [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/))

```
public String getDataAsJson() {
    return gson.toJson(someBeanOrSomeMap);
}
```

*(or just create the JSON object already during managed bean's (post)construction)*

The script will be able to access it as `data.someBeanPropertyOrMapKey`.

Comment: Thanks Bauke (long time no see my friend =]).
But I could not put them in a file because I'm gonna interact with data  from my database to form the chart.

Comment: I don't see why that would form a problem. If you want to pass variables from Java to JS, just create a global JS object which is to be used by the standalone script file, or let the JS get them by ajax.

Comment: Could you please just point me some link where I could see how to do this ? (both suggestions seems to fit my needs)

Comment: See updated answer for an example of creating the global JS variable. This is the easiest.

Comment: I'm trying to do what you said but I still don't get it.
I'm close to finish this, could you please take a look here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575009/how-use-database-in-javascript-and-jsf